# How can I create Setup package for wpf 4.5 application using some script

Tags: c#, wpf, installation, setup-project, .net-4.5

I need to create install-able setup via scripting for my WPF application. I don't know where to start and what is best way to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either:

- Use the built in setup project type in Visual Studio to create an MSI installer

  - [Tutorials](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual+studio+msi+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)
- Use something like [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) or [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). I use NSIS for all of my apps, both have learning curves and NSIS is fairly easily skinnable.

  - [NSIS Examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Where_can_I_find_some_example_scripts)
  - [WIX Examples](http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/examples/)

Comment: can you provide me any link. How to use it?

Comment: Check the tutorials on each site

Comment: i recommend using WIX it is very easy to learn how to use it. you can work with Visual Studio 2012.  http://wixtoolset.org/

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Inno Setup ▶ http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

It is free and also provides powerful script to make a installer package.

Comment: +1. Inno Setup has a wizard that will build you an installer within a few minutes of downloading the software. Once the wizard builds your install script, you can go the the `Run` menu and choose `Target Setup` or `Target Uninstall` to test your install/uninstall right from Inno Setup. Really fast and super easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Echilon. 
I would like to add that Inno Setup is also a very good solution to try.

IMHO WIX is much harder to understand and to manage than alternatives, for little projects it's not the best option.